# XSLT has to generate unique number for input record and append to the output record

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a requirement like in my input xml file `EMP_ID` will come multiple times, now while generating output record, it should come like below:

```
i/p:

123
123
456
789
456

o/p:
123|1
123|2
456|1
789|1
456|2
```

Please suggest how can this be implementted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `generate-id()` function.

No example code, because no code was given in the question.

Comment: <Input>
 <Record>
  <EMPID>FirstEmployee</EMPID>
 </Record> 
 <Record>
  <EMPID>SecondEmployee</EMPID>
 </Record>
 <Record>
  <EMPID>FirstEmployee</EMPID>
 </Record> 
 <Record>
  <EMPID>SecondEmployee</EMPID>
 </Record>
 
</Input>

<Output>
 <Record>
  <EMPID>FirstEmployee|1</EMPID>
 </Record>
 <Record>
  <EMPID>SecondEmployee|1</EMPID>
 </Record>
 <Record>
  <EMPID>FirstEmployee|2</EMPID>
 </Record>
 <Record>
  <EMPID>SecondEmployee|2</EMPID>
 </Record>
</Output>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and include your input **and** your current XSLT - see: [mcve]